# Save a value without making it change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a device who sends values continuously, until it is stopped.

I save these values inside an array.

```
deviceMonitoring( device2 ){
//there I populate this.arrayTimestamp and then copy the first value.
this.arrayElement = this.arrayTimestamp[0];
}
```

In other function I check the size of the `arrayTimestamp` and when it is greater than a certain size, I perform a certain action:

```
check(){
 that.timeout = setInterval(function() {
  if( (that.arrayTimestamp.length > 100 ){
   that.arrayTimestampCopy = that.arrayTimestamp.splice( 0, 100 )}
   DBwrite.write({
      arrayDivide: this.arrayTimestampCopy
      firstElement: this.arrayElement
   })
   }
  }, 1000);
 }
```

What I would like to achieve is that the `this.arrayElement` value always remains the same. On the other hand, when the condition of the if is satisfied and then the splice occurs, the `this.arrayElement` value changes.

How can I do??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `splice` you can use `slice` as slice won't modify the original array

```
   that.arrayTimestampCopy = that.arrayTimestamp.slice( 0, 100)}
```

Documentation for slice is here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: Ok I'll try, but after other 100 elements, the arrayTimestamp will have a size of 200?